# Help Understanding Instructions for Setting Up Git on a Mac

Tags: mac, installation, git

I'm trying to install Git on a mac. I found these instructions: [crainbandy](http://crainbandy.com/how-to/how-to-install-git-on-mac-os-x-leopard-snow-leopard)

But, I don't understand this bit.

```
1. Change directories to the mounted image
bash$ cd /Volumes/Git\ 1.6.4.4\ Intel\ Leopard/
bash$ ls
README.txt                    setup git PATH for non-terminal programs.sh
git-1.6.4.4-intel-leopard.pkg            uninstall.sh
bash$ ./setup\ git\ PATH\ for\ non-terminal\ programs.sh
2. Run the shell script (last line above)
```

Yep, they've given exact instructions. But, I don't know bash and I rarely use Terminal, so I need some help. Do I literally type in the part that reads README.txt? Do I literally type:

```
bash$ cd /Volumes/Git\ 1.6.4.4\ Intel\ Leopard/
bash$ ls
README.txt                    setup git PATH for non-terminal programs.sh
git-1.6.4.4-intel-leopard.pkg            uninstall.sh
bash$ ./setup\ git\ PATH\ for\ non-terminal\ programs.sh"
```

Do I need to change anything?

I don't want to mess anything up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NO**, do not literally type `bash$ ls …`. The part with `bash$` is your command prompt. You have to type everything *behind* that. So, in your case:

```
cd /Volumes/Git\ 1.6.4.4\ Intel\ Leopard/
ls
./setup\ git\ PATH\ for\ non-terminal\ programs.sh
```

---

If that doesn't work or seem to complicated, do yourself a favor and install Git using [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation). Run this:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"
```

… then wait until it finishes. Re-start your Terminal. Then run:

```
brew install git
```

And you're done.

Comment: hi slhck, Thank you for helping me. I understand about the $bash now. After inputting the line beginning ./setup\ git... I got this back: "The domain/default pair of (/Users/myname/.MacOSX/environment, PATH) does not exist
Variable PATH in ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist changed from '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin' to '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin'
~ /Volumes/Git 1.6.4.4 Intel Leopard
/Volumes/Git 1.6.4.4 Intel Leopard
Macintosh-2:Git 1.6.4.4 Intel Leopard bash$" Am I good to go? Thank you!

Comment: hi @slhck, I ran out of room in my previous comment. Is the fact that it couldn't find the domain/default pair a problem?  If I close Terminal and the open it again and then type "echo $PATH" It gives me: "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
". My bash$ prompt looks like: "Macintosh-2:~ myname$. I'm not sure what the Macintosh-2 bit means. Thank you very much for your detailed instructions. I really appreciate it. I'm trying to learn as much as I can.

Comment: It looks like the installer fixed this for you. When `git` is in your path, you should be ready to go! Your personal bash prompt is something like `<computer-name>:<folder> <your-username>`. You could change this, but it's not necessary. It could look different on every computer, the important thing is that when reading tutorials, the only thing you enter is everything after the `$`. Are you having any problems with the installation?

Comment: Thank you for the help! It worked. I installed Git in order to install Aptana. I should be all set. Sweet.

Comment: Sure, glad to help! Just post a new question if you have any problems!

Answer (score 1):

What they have shown is a transcript of their session, including what you type as well as the responses. So, in principle, the way to interpret it — if you don't already know what it means just from looking — is “Type the parts that aren't *already* on the screen”. Though, your prompt is likely slightly different from the “`bash$`” they show.

In that particular transcript, typing any of those lines completely would just result in a harmless error.

If you're interested in learning and you have even a vague feeling for how to read the stuff already (I suspect you do since you e.g. recognized the `README.txt` part probably isn't to be typed), then I think it would be not too dangerous for you to just go ahead and try figuring it out for yourself.

You could also follow any old "getting to know the Unix/Linux command line" tutorial for a bit until you know how to read prompt-vs-command-vs-output and what "cd" does, then work on this.

Comment: Hi @Kevin Reid, Thank you for the explanation and encouragement. I've got a lot to learn. This a crawl before you can walk situation. Thanks.